# Justifying one wrong thing by comparing it its opposite which is also wrong

Tags: phrases, idioms, logic

Is there a word or name for the phenomenon or syndrome in which people try to defend one wrong thing by comparing it something that is total opposite of it but also wrong?

For example:

> Drone attacks are the right thing because they are against terrorism which is wrong.

A more general but abstract kind of example could be:

> I want to kill all the sharks because they are dangerous for human beings.

Comment: Thinking of "two wrongs don't make a right" (but three lefts do) or "the cure is worse than the disease", but those are more reactions _to_ the phenomenon you describe. The logical fallacy undoubtedly has a name, but it escapes me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Andrew Leach's response, this is an example of **[consequentialism](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Consequentialism.html)**, a philosophical principle that holds

> that the consequences of one's conduct are the true basis for any judgment about the morality of that conduct.

The most common expression of this principle is the axiom *the ends justify the means*.

Answer (score 3):

This would appear to be at least substantially similar to ***the ends justifying the means,*** that is, the end result is so desirable that any method of achieving it is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Two wrongs don't make a right**.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/two-wrongs-don-t-make-a-right)
>   *Said to emphasize that it is not acceptable to do something bad to someone just because they did something bad to you first.*

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the actual meaning of "begging the question", which most people falsely use as "raises the question". From wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question

"Begging the question means 'assuming the conclusion (of an argument)', a type of circular reasoning. This is an informal fallacy where the conclusion that one is attempting to prove is included in the initial premises of an argument, often in an indirect way that conceals this fact.

The fallacy of petitio principii, or 'begging the question', is committed 'when a proposition which requires proof is assumed without proof'"

The examples from that wikipedia page include this sentence, which sounds a lot like your examples: "Opium induces sleep because it has a soporific quality".

See also: circular reasoning.